# Where's the clipboard stored in memory? Can it be swapped?

Tags: security, memory, encryption, operating-system, clipboard

### Context:

I'm starting to develop a password manager (Just for learning purposes). My goal right now is to copy the decrypted password to the clipboard, so it can be used somewhere else. In order to avoid decrypted passwords being swapped I had to [mlock](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock) the sensitive data

### Questions:

My concern now is: If I copy the decrypted password to clipboard, could it be swapped? Is there some way to prevent it from being swapped?

### Bonus Questions:

Where in memory space is clipboard actually stored? It's in the memory space of the process which called the clipboard to store data or it's in OS memory space?

Is posible to keep the password encrypted in the clipboard and just decrypt it when user pastes it? Like an event or a signal

If it's OS dependent, explain differences.

Answer (score 1):

In OS X it looks like any application running with the current user's permission can alter the clipboard contents at any time, whether it has the focus or not.

The following command line script will quite happily run in the background, applying [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) to the clipboard contents at regular intervals:

```
while true ; do sleep 1 ; pbpaste | tr A-Za-z N-ZA-Mn-za-m | pbcopy ; done &
```

This suggests that:

- the clipboard is stored in the OS memory space, and
- anything you copy to the clipboard is immediately available to every process belonging to you.

Fortunately, Apple's [Keychain Access utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_%28software%29#Keychain_Access) makes it unnecessary to use the clipboard when accessing stored passwords. I would imagine that any decent keychain software would also behave in this way.

However, there's no reason why you couldn't encrypt the data sent to the clipboard. With proper [authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication), it will be possible to keep the data secret while detecting if any tampering has taken place. (But obviously the application you're pasting the clipboard into will have to be able to decrypt it again.)